# Getting the first three bytes of an IP address

Tags: python

I want to use an IP address string, ie: 192.168.1.23 but only keep the first three bytes of the IP address and then append 0-255. I want to transform that IP address into a range of IP address' I can pass to NMAP to conduct a sweep scan.

The easiest solution of course is to simply trim off the last two characters of the string, but of course this won't work if the IP is 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.1.123

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
lhost = "192.168.1.23"

# Split the lhost on each '.' then re-assemble the first three parts
lip = self.lhost.split('.')
trange = ""
for i, val in enumerate(lip):
    if (i < len(lip) - 1):
        trange += val + "."

# Append "0-255" at the end, we now have target range trange = "XX.XX.XX.0-255"
trange += "0-255"
```

It works fine but feels ugly and not efficient to me. What is a better way to do this?

Comment: By first three bits, what do you mean? Could you please add some example input and output?

Comment: First, those are bytes, not bits.  Second, generally people use a mask to specify a range - i.e. `192.168.1.0/24`

Comment: @roippi My apologies for the "bits", I meant bits as in pieces not computer bits but I understand that is was not clear of me :p will correct that. Also at my Uni when talking about network design we certainly use the / notation to denote such a range but when passing ranges of IP to NMAP all my lecturers slides use ie 1-40. I didn't know NMAP could accept the / notation so thats cool!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the rfind function of string object.

```
>>> lhost = "192.168.1.23"
>>> lhost[:lhost.rfind(".")] + ".0-255"
'192.168.1.0-255'
```

The rfind function is similar with find() but searching from the end.

> rfind(...)
>       S.rfind(sub [,start [,end]]) -> int
>       Return the highest index in S where substring sub is found,
>       such that sub is contained within S[start:end].  Optional
>       arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.
>       Return -1 on failure.

A more complicate solution could use regular express as:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("\d{1,3}$","0-255",lhost)
'192.168.1.0-255'
```

Hope it be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You could split and get the first three values, join by a `'.'`, and then add `".0-255"`

```
>>> lhost = "192.168.1.23"
>>> '.'.join(lhost.split('.')[0:-1]) + ".0-255"
'192.168.1.0-255'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all IPs belong to class C. I think that the code must be flexible to accommodate various IP ranges and their masks,
I had previously written a tiny python module to calculate network ID< broadcast ID for a given IP address with any network mask.
code can be found here : https://github.com/brownbytes/tamepython/blob/master/subnet_calculator.py

I think networkSubnet() and hostRange() are functions which can be of some help to you.

Comment: That is really cool! In my particular instance I know I will only be dealing with class C address' but I will def take a closer look at your code.

Answer (score 0):

I like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

ip_address = '128.200.34.1'

list_ = ip_address.split('.')
assert len(list_) == 4
list_[3] = '0-255'

print('.'.join(list_))
```

Comment: Not sure I understand it as I've never seen **assert** before. Could you explain the last 3 lines?

Comment: assert checks something that should always be true.  list_[3] = '0-255' sets the fourth element of list_ to the string '0-255'.  print of course prints things.  '.'.join(list_) takes the elements of list and converts them to a string separated by dots.